# What is the difference in meaning between the words עֵ֭דֹתֶיךָ and עֵדְוֺתֶ֥יךָ

Tags: grammar-dikduk, translation

The word for “Your decrees” (Sefaria) appears in Tehillim 119 (& elsewhere) in two forms with and without the letter “vav”. The meanings seem to be identical but the pronunciation is different.

[Tehillim 119 (14)](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.119.14?lang=bi&lookup=%D7%A2%D9246%B5%D7%93%D6%B0%D7%95%D6%BA%D7%AA%D6%B6%D6%A5%D7%99%D7%9A%D6%B8&with=Lexicon&lang2=en)
עֵדְוֺתֶ֥יךָ

[Tehillim 119 (24)](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.119.24?lang=bi&lookup=%D7%A2%D6%B5%D6%AD%D7%93%D6%B9%D7%AA%D6%B6%D7%99%D7%9A%D6%B8&with=Lexicon&lang2=en) עֵ֭דֹתֶיךָ

What is the difference in meaning between the words עֵ֭דֹתֶיךָ and עֵדְוֺתֶ֥יךָ?

Comment: What makes you say that the meaning seems to be identical? That seems to be an answer to your question.

Comment: In the Targum on Tehillim both are rendered as סהדותך , so the same meaning. Assuming there's a chaseir vav in the latter case, perhaps your question should really be what linguistic phenomenon might cause the vav to be vocalized with a consonant in one case but not the other.  Or perhaps there are merely two similar variants of the same words which happens from time to time throughout Tanach.

Comment: @magicker72 The Sefaria translation of both forms is the same.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Which translation? Some are more reliable than others. The standard Sefaria translation is JPS which is definitely not Orthodox, and partly based on non-Jewish sources.

Comment: @N.T. As EraserX points out "In the Targum on Tehillim both are rendered as סהדותך". But anyway my question is "**What is the difference in meaning between the words עֵ֭דֹתֶיךָ and עֵדְוֺתֶ֥יךָ?**"

Comment: It's a good question. I've wondered myself. Just find a better source than sefaria translation.

Comment: There are identical translations in both pesukim for 9 translations; 5 in English and one in German, French and Yiddish.
There are apparently different translations in languages I do not understand. Can anyone help please?
Esperanto (1)
Viaj decidoj estas mia plezuro, Miaj konsilantoj.

Pri la vojo de Viaj leĝoj mi ĝojas, Kiel pri granda riĉeco.
La Malnova Testamento, L.L.Zamenhof [eo]

Polish (1)
Nawet wtedy świadectwa Twoje rozkoszą moją, doradcami mojemi. 

Drogą świadectw Twoich cieszę się ponad wszystkie skarby. 
Izaak Cylkow, 1841 - 1908

Comment: @EraserX
There is a slight difference is the Targum. סהדותך in posuk 14 has a sheva, while in posuk 24 it has a komatz. I'm not sure if that makes a difference. This theory is spoiled by the same word in perek 93 where the vov is not pronounced, but the targum does have a sheva. Avrohom Yitzchok
Have you seen the Radak? He mentions that there are 8 vov's that are pronounced in chapter 119. I don't think he explains the significance of this. Maybe we can discuss after maariv?

Comment: Yes iy"H. On which possuk is the Radak?

Comment: The Radak is on posuk 14

Comment: Perhaps your question ought to be larger, as in what are all the possible readings of this word and that word, when not vowelized. You need not limit to the targum. It is written in Ibn Gabbai's Avodat Hashem that when the scriptures are read without vowels then there are many possible or concurrent readings. Therefore you may read the chasser form as it as "Your Eidah's" - your communities, for example. The chasser form admits this reading, but the maleh form does not.

Comment: May be this is related to your question, [check it out](https://www.doresh-tzion.co.il/QAShowAnswer.aspx?qaid=18388)

Comment: @GembaliNoach Thank you for the reference. The Rav Mofsi there says that in Megilas Rus there are a few pesukim that do not start with a vov. The extra vov in eidvosecho each time it appears amkes up for the vov missing in Megilas Rus. (!!) What it does not explain is why is this necessary at all.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok May be we can find another source which explains why is this necessary

Comment: I posted that question on the Rav Mofsi site.

Comment: Interesting to note that all the pesukim starting with one of these letter, פר"ץ ב"ן דמ"ה, has עדותיך with a ו' חולם.

Answer (score 4):

One possible solution may lie in that עֵדְוֺתֶ֥יךָ in 119:14 is part of a phrase, בדרך עדותיך. While in 119:24 and in 93:5, the verse is discussing the actual עדתיך (i.e. not the דרך עדותיך).

Just to point out further, the Artscroll (Stone edition Tanach) translates the word in all three cases 'testimonies'.

Comment: The ArtScroll in their Kesuvim with a commentary (the big blue edition) explains why עדותיך/עדתיך means **Testimonies** . the quote R' Hirsch who links the term to עדי, ornament. By fulfilling these "memorial" precepts the Jew becomes ennobled and crowned with with splendour in his relationship with G-d. In Melachim II, 11:12 the posuk tells of a coronation  וַיִּתֵּ֤ן עָלָיו֙ אֶת־הַנֵּ֙זֶר֙ וְאֶת־הָ֣עֵד֔וּת, the fact that the person was crowned as a scion of the Davidic dynasty was a _testimony_ to his distinguished royal ancestry.

Comment: I've seen that the Minchas Shay expands on the Radak I mentioned previously.